# I'm trying to add a search functionality to my ListView but it gives Method Not Allowed (POST): error

Tags: python, django

My search form:

```
 <form class=" my-2 my-lg-0 d-flex flex-row-reverse" method=POST action="{% url 'memes:all' %}" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    </form>
```

My List View:

```
class MemeListView(ListView):
    model = Meme
    paginate_by = 100
    ordering = ['-created_at']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        search_value = self.request.GET.get("search", False)
        if search_value:
            memes = Meme.objects.filter(name_contains=search_value)
            objects = Meme.objects.filter(memes).select_related().distinct().order_by('-created_at')[:10]
            context['meme_list'] = objects
            context['search'] = search_value
        return context
```

My url:

```
path('', MemeListView.as_view(), name='all'),
```

error:
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4455

Method Not Allowed (POST): /all/

Method Not Allowed: /all/

[01/Feb/2022 19:23:22] "POST /all/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

I've done almost identical search functionality in my other crud and it seems to work. What's the issue?

Comment: A `ListView` does not processes POST request: only views that create/update/delete items do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search is normally done through a GET request, not a POST request: POST requests are usually used to create, update and delete entities.

So your form should have `method="GET"`:

```
<form class=" my-2 my-lg-0 d-flex flex-row-reverse" method="GET" action="{% url 'memes:all' %}">
    …
</form>
```

Since this is a GET request, it is not necessary to use `{% csrf_token %}` since cross-site request forgery will not result in creating, updating or removing an entity.

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to solve my problem, however a new one arose. When I search a "Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name." which makes no sense because:
1) it doesn't pop out when loading a ListView without search
2) It pops out even after I comment out logout part from my code

Comment: @HubertBudny: if you used an `app_name` like you probably did here, it is `{% url 'memes:logout' %}` so prefixed with the app name.

Comment: @HubertBudny: how do you comment this out? With `{# ... #}`? Note that if you use `<!-- ... -->`, Django will still render that part of the template.

Comment: I erased the part completely just to be safe and it still popped out

Comment: @HubertBudny: you should restart the server: Django caches templates so it is possible that you simply have the result of a cached template.

Comment: The thing I noticed while testing is it only pops op if there aren't any records that fit the search. If I test it on a meme that has a title containing search string it works just fine